# How to preserve the installation option of the specific home-brewed packages when upgrading them?

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-managers

Every time I "brew upgrade", the packages I installed with my own option will just be installed with their default configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew uses the `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json` file (stored at `$(brew --prefix $PACKAGE)/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json`) to determine what options to use when upgrading. It will store the options used to install a formula originally.

Comment: Turns out that they've been upgraded well this time. Anyway, it helps. Thanks.